# sforce.apex.execute invalid or unexpected token

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/resource/1468830130000/ConnectionJsNoAgent")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("SendSms","callSendWSrvId", "{id'{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.Id}'}"); 
alert('result '); 
window.location.reload();
```

I keep getting errors and no matter what i do i cant seem to get it to work.
I tried it with a @future @remoteAction and standard methods.

```
@future (callout = true)
    public static void sendWSrvId(String Id) {
//logic
}
```

Update: Forgot to mention I' using this in a custom button.

Update 2: Error after switching to webservice [image]

Comment: after Id you forgot :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params object (third parameter to sforce.apex.execute) should be a normal object, not a string. Also, that means your code is malformed.

Here's a corrected version of your JavaScript:

```
var result = sforce.apex.execute("SendSms","callSendWSrvId", {id: '{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.Id}'});     
alert(result);
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the third param should be set.

Comment: @user8310 It should be a normal JavaScript object or JSON string. I normally avoid writing JSON manually when I can avoid it. Also, as Jsm said, the Apex should be webservice. See my JavaScript example in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are invoking a method from a Custom button it should be a **webService** method.

Try this:

**Apex Class:**

```
global class SendSms {
        webService static void sendWSrvId(Id recId) {
            //logic
        }
    }
```

**Button code:**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/resource/1468830130000/ConnectionJsNoAgent")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("SendSms","sendWSrvId", "{recId: '{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.Id}'}"); 
alert('result '); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: I switched  it to a webservice but its still not working. I copied your code as well in case i missed something but it didnt change anything.